# Error while installing cocoa pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode8.2

While I am installing cocoa pod in my system, I got following error.

**Error :**

"[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`. You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`."

**pod file:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Demo

  target 'DemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'DemoUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
 pod 'AZSClient'
  pod 'CardIO'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'OpenTok'
  pod 'THCalendarDatePicker', '~> 1.2.6'
end
```

Comment: Can you include your podfile?

Comment: try to uninstall pod and install latest pod that will help you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Write the pod file using these lines:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
target “GoogleAnalyticsTestApp” do
   pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
end
```

**Do not** write **Google/Analytics**. Write **GoogleAnalytics**. Hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and some times it just happened by the mismatch version of the required cocoa and cocoa pod.

My solution is as follows :

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

If you still follow any issue then let me know.

Change your pod file with this:

```
`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Demo

 pod 'AZSClient'
  pod 'CardIO'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'OpenTok'
  pod 'THCalendarDatePicker', '~> 1.2.6'
end`

  target 'DemoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'DemoUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

Comment: pod repo remove master and pod setup command has been executed successfully. But pod install command execution results in the following error:    [!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Comment: @Krishu Recheck my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't use target in target.

Try this.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Demo' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Demo
  pod 'AZSClient'
  pod 'CardIO'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'OpenTok'
  pod 'THCalendarDatePicker', '~> 1.2.6'

end

target 'DemoTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end

target 'DemoUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing
end
```

Comment: and currently 'CardIO' repository is not working.
so you have to check 'CardIO' repository. or remove 'CardIO' temporary.

Comment: Okay..I will check it.